# What can be proven within Simply Typed lambda calculus?

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus, type-theory

I was reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_typed_lambda_calculus and I'm having a hard time thinking of anything remotely interesting that can be proven within Simply Typed lambda calculus.

Am I wrong?  Or do you need dependent types to prove anything interesting.

Comment: Do you mean proven within the **simply** typed $\lambda$-calculus? The Wikipedia page you cite discusses lots of different typed $\lambda$-calculi some of which are very expressive indeed.

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

According to same article in Wikipedia simply typed lambda calculus is equivalent to minimal logic. Maybe it can be simpler to find what can be proven by minimal logic. Then you can choose what you think is interesting.

Comment: So is the computation component essentially pointless?  Minimal logic doesn't seem that useful either.

Comment: Simply Typed Lambda Calculus is simplest type system I've seen. If you need something more expressive you need to use more powerful type system.

Answer (score 0):

That Wikipedia article sort of overstates what can be proven in simply-typed lambda calculus as minimal logic, which includes $(B\to (A\land \neg A))\to \neg B$, which doesn’t necessarily have meaning in the implicational fragment of propositional intuitionistic logic (which is what corresponds). So yes it is super simple and mainly a foundation for more complexly typed lambda calculi

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).